# Maximise and Minimise Div - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to use jQuery to get a div to increase it's height to 300px when clicked, but if it's already 300px (i.e. maximised) then it should reduce its height to 40px if clicked. I know this is probably an absolute beginners question, but I'm really new to jQuery and haven't been able to find an answer thus far.

So far all I've managed is the minimize code:

```
$("#banner_animate").click(function(){
  $("#banner_animate").animate({
    height: "40px"
  }, 500 );
});
```

Some help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Besides the jquery solutions i would suggest using a CSS one (*CSS transitions combined with jQuery*)

two css rules

```
#banner_animate{
   height:300px;
   transition: height 0.5s linear;
}

#banner_animate.minimized{
   height:40px;
}
```

and just add/remove the `minimized` class

```
$("#banner_animate").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('minimized');
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/CsttH/

Answer (score 0):

Check $("#banner_animate").height() and add logic to to set a "new height" variable accordingly.
Either 40 or 300

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fD7xz/

```
$('#banner_animate').click(function() {
  var height = $('#banner_animate').height() == 300 ? 40 : 300;
  $('#banner_animate').animate({ height: height + 'px' }, 500 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#banner_animate").click(function(){
    var h = $(this).height() == 300 ? 40 : 300;
    $(this).animate({
        height: h
    }, 500 );
});
```

The variable declaration above is a ternary operator...we test the height to see if it's 300, if it is, then `h` is 40, otherwise, `h` is 300.